# Clipboard not accessible from background app with Android 10 SDK upgrade

Tags: android, clipboard, copy-paste, android-10.0

The copy/paste feature used to work in my app. But once I have upgraded my apps SDK to target Android 10, it doesn't get the correct data. 
Eg. If I copy "Hello" from chrome, open my app and paste it, Hello is pasted.
Now if I go to chrome without killing my app and copy "World", open my app and paste, "Hello" is pasted.

There have been some changes related to privacy in Android 10: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#clipboard-data

My `onPrimaryClipChanged()` callback isn't triggered on Android 10 with my app getting the SDK upgrade as well.

Is there any solution to this, kindly give a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There's only one solution: asking for permission `android.permission.READ_LOGS` and then use `logcat` or `dumpsys` command to get the clipboard. This permission must be granted via `ADB`.

Comment: What is the significant of `android.permission.READ_LOGS` for this? Why does it have anything to do with the clipboard?

Comment: @greywolf82 I'm able to access the logs with logcat but am not finding any clipboard information. Do you have to set the READ_LOGS permission per application? And/or like anirudhmb says do I need to also set WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS??

Answer (score -2):

As you already mentioned, you are facing this issue because of the OS upgrade.
However you can resolve this by requesting special permissions from ADB.

It can be done as follows -

1. Enable Developer mode on you phone
2. Install ADB on your personal computer
3. Enable USB debugging after connecting your phone to your personal computer
4. On your computer, open the cmd/terminal in the folder where the extracted files 
   of ADB exist, and type the following one after the other-

```
(on windows)
adb -d shell appops set <package name> SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW allow

adb shell pm grant <package name> android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS

adb shell pm grant <package name> android.permission.READ_LOGS

adb shell am force-stop <package name>


(on mac)

./adb -d shell appops set <package name> SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW allow

./adb shell pm grant <package name> android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS

./adb shell pm grant <package name> android.permission.READ_LOGS

./adb shell am force-stop <package name>
```

The `<package name>` is the root package name that is defined in the development code. It will be similar to `com.example.myapp`.